# Tricky SQL query, maybe some sort of join would work?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a SQL query that I'm trying to write, but I'm not quite sure how to get it to work.

I have three tables: "s", "t", and "st" (which is a map between "s" and "t".

```
table s
=======
primary key sID   |   val
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
       a              0
       b              1
       c              5
       d              6
       e              7



table t
=======
primary key tID   |   val
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
      nul               -1
      bbb                2
      ccc                3
      ddd                4



table st
========
foreign key sID   |  foreign key tID
(unique)          |  (multiple sID to one tID, meaning tID is not unique)
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
       a                    ddd
       b                    ccc
       c                    nul
       d                    ccc
       e                    bbb
```

So, all 's' have to be mapped to a 't', but ones which are not at a real 't' are instead mapped to the default/null 't' (nul).

The val's are unique across both 's' and 't', meaning that if table 's' has a 1, then table 't' cannot have a 1.

---

**So my problem is the following:**

Given a set of vals (which can be either 's' or 't'), I need to get the sID and tID in the 'st' table of the corresponding IDs. The problem is that if a 's' is in the set but it's 't' is NOT in the set, I need to get the values (sID, 'nul') rather than (sID, tID).

For example, given the values (3, 1, 6), it would return the pairs: (b,ccc); (d,ccc);

Given the values (0,4), it would return the pair: (a,ddd)

However, given the values (6), it would need to return (d, **nul**) since the val 3 (which corresponds to ccc which is what d is mapped to) is not in the set. I don't need null 's' though, just null 't'.

---

I was thinking of using the following statement, but that doesn't help me with returning "id, nul" if only the 's' is in the set but not 't'.

```
SELECT st.sID, st.tID FROM t, st WHERE t.tID=st.tID AND (t.val=%_VAL1_% OR t.val=%_VAL_2 OR ......);
```

That gives me anything that has both a 't' and a 's' in the set (really it gives me all 's' associated with any 't' that are in the set), but it doesn't give me the 's' that are by themselves.

Perhaps I could post-process anything that's in 's' but not in 'st', but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm rather stuck.

Thanks!

*(note: s, t, and st are not my real table names, don't worry. Also, the primary key's are actually text GUIDs, unfortunately, but I tried to make it simpler to distinguish)*

Comment: If I'm not getting it wrong, from your model and data I can see you have 3 tables to model a one-to-many relationship. Why not use just 2? You said `all 's' have to be mapped to a 't'`, then why not add the FK to 't' in 's'?

Comment: It was mainly for extensibility purposes and to keep interfaces somewhat similar to what they were before I started using sqlite.

Comment: This database model looks rather strange. Could you share more about motivations for it - perhaps a different model would serve you better? Also, what's the difference between row `{c, null}` existing in `st` and such row not existing at all?

Comment: If the values of 3,1,6 would return b,ccc and d,ccc, why would the value of 6 return d,null? 6 corresponds to d, which is mapped to ccc. Or am I misreading something?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: The model somewhat comes from trying to integrate with a pre-existing setup which used c++ std::maps instead of a relational database, although I agree it might not have been the best choice. Likewise, the need to return c, null comes from a need in c++ for something that I'm trying to do (in particular, merging subsets of the database into another database based on the val).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: "Null" actually has a value in my table, as there was a thought that we might want to have floating 's'  that aren't used, meaning that they would need to be distinguished from 's' which are just not mapped to a 't', but used. Perhaps I could have just added another boolean val or something, but again it was meant to be consistent with the way things were before.

Comment: @KevinFairchild: The idea behind that is that since (3) is not in the set, (6) is not being mapped to any 't', so it needs to be removed from it's mapping and instead mapped to a null 't'. As I said above, it's mainly for dealing with merging of subsets of tables based on a given "val".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
SELECT s.sID, t.tID
FROM st
    LEFT JOIN s
        ON s.sID = st.sID AND s.val IN (6)
    LEFT JOIN t
        ON t.tID = st.tID AND t.val IN (6)
WHERE NOT(s.sid IS NULL AND t.tid IS NULL)
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle that proves it for all 3 scenarios](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13a57/12). You have to have the mapping table as the main, since the resultset is from tables that can be null.

Although, this is very weird logic. Usually if a mapping is not hit in many-to-many relationship, you just return 0 rows, not a partial....

If you want to cancel out the duplicates that might occur from multiple mapping misses (null in one column output), then add a DISTINCT. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.sID, t.tID
FROM st
    LEFT JOIN s
        ON s.sID = st.sID AND s.val IN (6)
    LEFT JOIN t
        ON t.tID = st.tID AND t.val IN (6)
WHERE NOT(s.sid IS NULL AND t.tid IS NULL)
```

[Here is the fiddle that shows the duplication](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b560/1)

[And, here is the one that fixes it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b560/2)

**AND Finally, based on latest update.** If you want any NULL s columns to be excluded, just make s an INNER JOIN and you can then remove the NULL check since you will not get double NULL's now...Feel free to remove the distinct if you do want multiple `sID|NULL` results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.sID, t.tID
FROM st
    JOIN s
        ON s.sID = st.sID AND s.val IN (6)
    LEFT JOIN t
        ON t.tID = st.tID AND t.val IN (6)
```

[Here is the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b560/10)

Comment: That doesn't appear to quite work either. It works for the case of just a 6 (although it also returns a bunch of null rows), but if I use (6,3) it seems to return the right val, then a bunch of null rows, and then a few rows of a null sID but the same tID (ccc). And yes, I realize that this is very weird logic :p

Comment: You may want to add a `WHERE NOT (s.sid IS NULL AND t.tid IS NULL)` at the end since sqlfiddle is hiding a lot of null results.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson You are right. Updated the code, and will have a new SQL fiddle link shortly

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yeah, then when I use (6,3) it returns several rows: (d,ccc); (NULL,ccc) ; (NULL,ccc) (at least in my code, perhaps because I have additional data). Perhaps I can filter that later, though not sure why I'm getting multiple return vals.

Comment: You need to adjust your query a little for the (6,3) case; `SELECT s.sid, t.tid
FROM st
LEFT JOIN s
ON s.sId = st.sId AND s.val IN (0,4)
LEFT JOIN t 
ON s.sId = st.sId AND t.tid = st.tid AND t.val IN (0,4)
WHERE NOT (s.sid IS NULL AND t.tid IS NULL)`

Comment: @Jordan OK, SQLFiddle is updated, and so is the question. When I run it against 3.6 I only get one NULL ccc, but if you have additional data, then you could add a distinct

Comment: @Jordan Here is the fiddle that duplicates: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b560/1          AND here is the one with distinct to fix it   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b560/2   I will update the answer

Comment: @JustinPihony: If I add "distinct" it gives me two values (NULL, ccc) and (d, ccc). You get it too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b560/3  Side note: Sqlfiddle is awesome, I didn't know it existed. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan Yes, that is correct. because you are hitting on ccc mapping to b,c,d in my fiddle. However, d is the only one that matches, the others get nulls. I would imagine you want both results based on your criteria?

Comment: @JustinPihony Just the results which have (d, NULL) and (d,ccc) preferably, not (NULL,ccc). I can probably filter that out after though in my c++.

Comment: @Jordan http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b560/9 will work then. I will change my query. However, you should also edit your question to specify you do not want null S's. Basically, just make S an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Awesome, that got it. Thanks! You guys are awesome. Question edited, my bad.

Comment: @Jordan Answer updated. You dont need the WHERE clause since you will be guaranteed no double null due to the INNER JOIN now

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_join#Left_outer_join):

```
SELECT s.sid AS sid, t.tid AS tid
  FROM s
  LEFT JOIN st
    ON s.sid = st.sid
  LEFT JOIN t
    ON t.tid = st.tid
WHERE s.val IN (3, 1, 6)
  AND t.val IN (3, 1, 6)
```

Comment: Yup, that's the problem. If I just use "6' it returns the whole set (d, ccc)

Comment: Nope, still not right. Try it against my sqlfiddle setup. Now you have turned your t's left joins into an inner join by putting the filter logic in the where. Since s or t can be null, you have to have st in the from